# Issue updating database passing $argv and launching the same script multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, argv, nohup

In an Ubuntu web server am trying to update a MySQL database launching the same script simultaneously to update different portions of the database at the same time.

I am using nohup for multiple launches and i pass in the parameters for the variable with $argv

the command I am using looks like this:

```
nohup php /filepath/myscript.php A
nohup php /filepath/myscript.php B
nohup php /filepath/myscript.php C
```

...and so on

A, B, C, are parameters passing in the query to the database with $argv.

The problem is that if i launch a single command:

```
php /filepath/myscript.php A
```

I have no issue and the DB updates normally.

If i launch more than one at the same time (the are in total 108 lines) the database I want to update gets more empty, as in more cells become blank, instead of filling up.

What am I getting wrong? I tried launching without nohup using multiple terminal windows but I obtain the same opposite result.... please help!

Comment: It seems your script is doing something wrong, we cannot help you without further information

Comment: Why not store parameters in file and read it with one script run?

Comment: the script queries the DB, finds if there is an update to send back, and then writes it to the DB...if there was something wrong with it, why would it work when I launch a single command?

Comment: you have to detail what you are doing in your script , maybe there are conditions (yuo did in your script) wich do the job perfecty when resources are dedicated but in more complex scenarios like concurrent requests are likely to not work properly. So please post the script or a prototype